# Simple 3D programming to view a model

Tags: opengl, 3d, 3d-model

I have some code that is manipulating some 3D models, for checking properties of the model and doing some calculations.

I have the facet information and want to be able to pass this information on to another function or program so that it can be displayed. All I really need is something that can display the model in 3D so I can check my code is doing what I think it is doing.

I would like to do this in C++ but have tried other options as well.
I have tried a 3d view port in C#, opengl 2 in python, and opengl 3.x with glew in C++. Some of these have got close to working how I want them to but they are way more complex than just a function I can pass a list of vertex information to. And have ended up spending several weeks trying to figure this out.

Is there a tutorial for a simpler way to just display a 3D model?
I would prefer a C++ function I can just pass my facet information into, but would also be happy with another language or just a simple program that I can load and view the model in.

If opengl is the best thing for this then I would like to understand should I be developing for opengl 2.x or 3.x or 4.x or are they all backwards or forwards compatible? And then should I be using glew or SDL or freeglut or glut. Or are these more for games engines and overkill for just displaying a simple model?

Comment: You can export the model to .stl format - it is very simple. There are many free stl viewers.

Comment: .stl doesn't support color so I can't highlight the sections of the model I am manipulating then

Comment: you can write a simple software renderer, if graphical quality is not an issue. It will be _far_ easier to manipulate than opengl.